# From the representations of $SO(n)$ to its projective group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

$SO(n)$'s rep $\rho: SO( n) \to SL(d,\mathbf{R})$ for some dimension d of representations (reps).

The projective group $PSO(n)$'s rep $\rho'$ must be a rep of $SO(n)$'s rep $\rho$. But $SO( n)$'s rep $\rho$ must be a rep of $PSO( n)$'s rep $\rho'$.

But what are the constraints of the $\rho'$ such that which $\rho$ are not survived in $\rho'$?

- Does the adjoint rep $(n(n-1)/2)$-dim rep  of $SO(n )$ survive in $PSO( n)$?
- Does the vector rep ($n$-dim rep)  of $SO(n )$ not survive in $PSO( n)$?
- What are the rules of the general reps of $SO( n)$ that survived or not in $PSO( n)$?

Comment: Just make sure the $SO(n)$-representation has kernel containing $Z(SO(n))$ and you will get a representation of $PSO(n)$.

Comment: Really?  Even for defining representation of $SO(n)$ for all $n$?

Comment: I meant to say, do you mean that "the ()-representation :()→(,) , has kernel of this map, containing (()) in  ())?"

Comment: Yes.  The representation factors through PSO(n) (i.e., $\rho$ is $SO(n)\xrightarrow{\pi}PSO(n)\xrightarrow{\bar\rho} SL(d,\mathbb{R})$) iff $\ker\rho\geq\ker\pi=Z(SO(n))$, which is a special case of the universal property of quotients.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3108122/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/347459/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3762807/96384.

Comment: One thing to note is that the adjoint rep should always work. Any Lie group with a given Lie algebra has an adjoint representation. Under some basic assumptions (algebraically closed I think is all we need) these are all the same rep.